# Display a webpage in Mac lock screen

Tags: macos

I want to leave my Mac locked, but display a web page (representing a web-based dashboard) in the lock screen. The idea is to leave this web dashboard showing 24x7 but without letting anyone else get access to the rest of the system.

Comment: as a screen shot of the web page ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - no; as I want the dynamic webpage rendered with JS behaviours intact. nicael's answer below does exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can download [this screensaver](https://code.google.com/p/websaver/downloads/list) which allows you to specify the site you want to display (found [there](https://superuser.com/questions/759599/showing-webpages-as-a-screensaver-in-mac-os-x)).
2. Turn on the password to make your screensaver to be the lock screen:

   1. Open "System Preferences"
   2. Go to "Security & Privacy"

   [image]

   3. Check "Require password [immediatly] after sleep or screensaver begins"

      [image]

Comment: Excellent. I wish there was a way to zoom the web page, but then I can workaround it by writing a proxy web site.

Comment: https://github.com/liquidx/webviewscreensaver looks like an alternative that builds and works on newer versions of macOS.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in a product my team and I are about to release, called Screensaver Ninja. True to its name, the ninja transforms your screensaver into a rotation of live websites like dashboards, analytics, news, the weather...whatever you need.

Apart from being able to lock your computer as detailed above, you can also choose to lock the screensaver so that whilst everyone can view the data, you must have a keycode to access it.

Comment: Thanks for self-disclosing your affiliation. Be sure to participate for reasons other than promotion to avoid posts being deleted by the community.